# unsupported vs not supported

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference, prefixes

I have often seen in software sentences like "Feature is not supported."

What about using "unsupported"?
Are they differences of meaning / usage between these two?

**EDIT:** Sorry for people who answered already, I did not mean to write "yet" at the end of the first sentence. The question was actually about "not supported" and "unsupported".

Comment: I think that "un..." words would be perceived as more negative. Your eye keys on single words, so its "supported" vs. "unsupported". Comprehending the "not" is secondary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Unsupported" and "not supported" have the same meaning, but if you want to imply that it will be supported at some time in the future, you need to use the phrase "not yet", as in "not yet supported" or "not supported yet". It's quite all right for the "not yet" to be separated by the word it is qualifying, but it doesn't really make sense to use "yet unsupported".

Answer (score 5):

I write software documentation, so I feel qualified to answer this question. In software, when we say that a feature is not supported yet (or not yet supported), we are implying that while the feature isn't supported right now, we recognize that this may be something we do in the future.

Often we use "Feature is not supported yet" or "Feature not yet supported" to give the impression to the customer that we know this is probably something that they will want in the future, and we are actively considering including it in the product, but it hasn't been implemented yet.

On the other hand, when we say a feature is unsupported, we are simply making the statement that the software won't do that. We don't imply whether we think it *ought* to, or whether we think it *will* do in the future. It is just a simple factual statement.

Simply saying a feature is "unsupported" doesn't suggest any reason. It could be any of the following:

1. Because it was supported in the past, and support has be deprecated, or
2. We recognize that it is a feature that we aren't ever going to be able to support (software built on the .NET framework is never going to get native support on MacOS), or
3. Maybe we haven't looked into it yet, or
4. Maybe we have almost finished developing this feature and it will be in the next release

We simply don't know because we haven't been given any context.